# How to differentiate $(\ln (\tan^{-1} x))^{\tan^2 x}$

Tags: calculus

So I want to differentiate the following function:

$$ (log(cotx))^{(tanx)^2} $$

I used https://www.derivative-calculator.net/ to see how it is done but I do not get even the second step.

$$ \frac{d}{dx}[(log(cotx))^{(tanx)^2}] = (log(cotx))^{(tanx)^2}.\frac{d}{dx}[log(log(cotx)).(tanx)^2] $$

I know the general power rule:

$$ x^n=nx^{n-1} $$

So I assume that is what happens first but then I do not understand why there is a log inside of a log. I think there is a property of logarithms I don't know about.

Comment: Have you heard of or seen logarithmic differentiation?

Comment: Or computer-based symbolic differentiation?  $$\log ^{\tan ^2(x)}(\cot (x)) \left(2 \tan (x) \sec ^2(x) \log (\log (\cot
   (x)))-\frac{\tan (x) \sec ^2(x)}{\log (\cot (x))}\right)$$

Comment: Hi Daniel - note that `\log x` ($\log x$) is prettier than `log x` $(log x)$. Similar for $\cot, \tan$, etc.  I've edited the post. Cheers.

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward integral if you take logs and know the chain rule and product rule. However, it's definitely tedious (and I don't personally find the solution very satisfying).

Answer (score 2):

Call the function $y$ and take logs
\begin{eqnarray*}
y=  (\log(\cot x))^{(\tan x)^2} \\ 
\log( y)= {(\tan x)^2} \log( \log(\cot x)) \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}
Now differentiate 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} =  \frac{-\csc^2 x(\tan x)^2}{(\cot x)( \log(\cot x) )}  + 2\tan x \sec x \log( (\log(\cot x))\\ 
 \frac{dy}{dx} = \left( \frac{-\csc^2 x(\tan x)^2}{(\cot x)( \log(\cot x) )}  + 2\tan x \sec x \log( (\log(\cot x))\right) (\log(\cot x))^{(\tan x)^2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1):

That step is using the fact that
$$f^g=e^{\log f^g} =e^{g\log f}.$$
So you can use the chain rule $(e^u)’=e^u\cdot u’$ to see that 
$$(f^g)’ =(e^{g\log f})’$$
$$=(e^{g\log f})\cdot(g\log f)’$$
$$=f^g \cdot (g\log f)’$$